# Transformation of binary data

Tags: optimization, transformation, binary

I have a function that I try to optimize using Particle Swarm Optimization. Objective function gets a binary string. So these binary strings are candidate solutions of the subject function. I can measure the dissimilarity between two solution, but I need to move one solution towards another by a factor, meaning I need a vector. Is there any methods to do that?

Example:

```
a = 0011001 
b = 0011010
```

I want to move `a` towards `b` by the factor of 0.4. So I need to find another string that is similarity between `a` is 0.6 and similarity between `b` is 0.4.

I hope I could explain myself clear.

Comment: How is 'similarity' defined?

Comment: Basically, two binary string is 100% similar if all characters are equal: a[i] = b[i].

Comment: In your example `a` and `b` have length 7 and differ by two bits. So would the similarity be 2/7? In that case we can't move towards by a factor of 0.4 because the similarity is already greater than 60%. Am I understand this correctly that each similar bit gives a similarity of 14%? (when we have strings on length 7)

Comment: Actually strings are much longer. I am trying to somehow represent binary data n-dimensional space and then represent a vector from one point to another.